# Retrieving Google Contacts always omits custom fields

Tags: c#, .net, api, contacts

I have a bunch of Google Contacts, and I've added custom fields to most of them (using the standard Google web interface). When I use the following code to retrieve the contacts into my C# program, the contacts all get downloaded, but I can't seem to find the custom field data anywhere. I was expecting to find it in the ExtendedProperties collection, but that invariably contains zero items. Here is my code, assume a correct user name and password string:

```
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;

...

RequestSettings settings;
ContactsRequest cr;

settings = new RequestSettings("GoogleContactsUtility", accountName, accountPassword);
settings.AutoPaging = true;
cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);

Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();

foreach (Contact entry in f.Entries)
    // entry.ExtendedProperties is always empty!
```

Bearing in mind that this code is a snippet from a program that builds and runs successfully, and retrieves all my contacts such that I can get at the standard fields, what am I doing wrong that I can't retrieve the custom fields?